# Why does PHP fwrite() fail when inside of a Wordpress plugin call?

Tags: php, wordpress

My goal is to write a Wordpress plugin that writes out a file whenever a post gets saved.  Below is the existing code for the plugin, minus the plugin header info:

```
<?php       
add_action( 'save_post', 'write_hook' );

function write_hook( $post_id ) {
    $myFile = "target.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
    fwrite($fh, "ANOTHER LINE\n");
    fclose($fh);
    wp_mail( 'myemail@address.com', $post_title, $post_url );
}
?>
```

When I save a post, the mail goes through but target.txt remains untouched.  I don't see any errors written out to the logs.  Target.txt has permissions of 777, and the non-plugin code below works correctly (and is in the same directory as the plugin).  It updates target.txt and displays 'woot' on the page when I access it directly.

```
<?php
    $myFile = "target.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
    fwrite($fh, "ANOTHER LINE hooray\n");
    fclose($fh);
    echo "woot";
?>
```

What am I doing wrong in my Wordpress plugin code?

Comment: None of that would produce errors for logs. did you check if the file is properly opened? assuming fopen() succeeds is not a good thing.

Comment: Try using an absolute path to the file.

Comment: Odds are your file path is dissimilar to your original test and your WP plugin code is indeed working, but putting the target.txt in a different place than you expect.

Comment: I will check to make sure that fopen() works, and look for another target.txt file on the system.  I hadn't been thinking about execution context and how it would impact the file location, but that sounds a likely culprit.  Thanks!

Comment: Following up: @phpisuber01 had it.  Target.txt appeared in my /wp-admin directory because of the execution context.

Answer (score 2):

After following the advice in the comments, I confirmed that the issue was that the execution context of the script changed depending on whether the fwrite() was invoked as a stand-alone page or as part of a Wordpress plugin.

In the stand-alone page, the local path put it in the same directory as the script.

In the plugin, the local path syntax means that fwrite() wrote target.txt into the /wp-admin folder, because that's the local path at the time the plugin was invoked.